# Display static content in Wordpress if page/post empty

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to display a message if the Wordpress page is empty (eg. "Still under progress").

My loop looks like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Main-menu open -->
<div id ="menu-maincontent">

<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>

<h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>


</div>
<!-- Main-menu close -->

<!-- Main-content open -->
<div id="main-content">

<!-- Main-content-in open -->
<div id="main-content-in">

<?php the_content(); ?>

</div>

<div class="cleared"></div>

<?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
<?php endif; // End if comments_open() ?>

</div><!-- Main-content close -->

<?php  endwhile; ?> 

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

How could I code in this message? It would be even better if I could have a separate PHP file that I call in with it (as I have a lot of page-templates in the theme).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only changed the part which was necessary, which is *div#main-content-in*.

```
<!-- Main-content-in open -->
<div id="main-content-in">

<?php 
    // Get the content
    $content = get_the_content();

    if(trim($content) == "") // Check if the string is empty or only whitespace
    {
        echo "Static content";
        get_template_part('slug','name');
    }
    else
    {
        // Apply filters the same as the_content() does: 
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
        $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
        echo $content;
    }
?>

</div>
<!-- Main-content-in close -->
```

Sources:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: Great, thank you, this works. Only thing is I get an empty space with &#65279; echoed somewhere, but I can't find where?

Comment: Well, I'm guessing that's coming from `get_template_part('slug','name')`, unless you changed that to something meaningfull (an actual viewpart you can call) or removed it.  Otherwise I have no idea where that should be coming from.

Comment: This is the content of the php loaded:
<div id="nocontent">
<p>Feltöltés alatt...</p>
<p>Nézzen vissza később</p>

And this is generated:

<div id="main-content-in">

&#65279;<div id="nocontent">
<p>Feltöltés alatt...</p>
<p>Nézzen vissza később</p>
</div>
</div>

Comment: I have no idea where that is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Check what I did in end while

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <!-- Main-menu open -->
    <div id ="menu-maincontent">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>

    <h2><?php echo the_title(); ?></h2>


    </div>
    <!-- Main-menu close -->

    <!-- Main-content open -->
    <div id="main-content">

    <!-- Main-content-in open -->
    <div id="main-content-in">

    <?php the_content(); ?>

    </div>

    <div class="cleared"></div>



  <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
    <?php endif; // End if comments_open() ?>

    </div><!-- Main-content close -->

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

  <? require('page_not_found.php'); ?>


    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```